# Proxying MetaSploit through BurpSuite

Tags: http, proxy, metasploit, packet, burp-suite

I was wondering how I would be able to proxy MetaSploit through BurpSuite.

I was to reverse engineer a packet being sent to my ChromeCast, but I have no way of viewing the packet.

Thanks.

Comment: Would using Wireshark be an option?

Comment: I just tried that, but I have to get familiar with BurpSuite for my ethical hacking course, but yes, WireShark did work.

Comment: Bear in mind that Burp is mainly for web application security. It won't help you much with analyzing arbitrary protocols.

Comment: But would it still work?

Comment: I guess Burp would choke on the parts that aren't HTTP or protocols recognized by Burp.

Comment: Understandable, have a nice day

Answer (score 8):

Use the PROXIES environment variable (while in msfconsole) :

```
set PROXIES HTTP:127.0.0.1:8080
```

Or run Metalsploit with proxychains (config at /etc/proxychains.conf) http://proxychains.sourceforge.net

Notice that using burp is not helpful to inspect protocols other than http.